# Conjugate transpose in R

Tags: r, linear-algebra, eigen, complex-numbers

I am trying to compute the conjugate transpose in R.
Here I perform an eigendecomposition on an asymmetric matrix. I expect that the eigenvectors $U$ should be a unitary matrix and therefore the conjugate tranpose $U^*$ should equal its inverse $U^{-1}$. However, they are unequal.
I expect the issue is one of the following:

1. My eigendecomposition code `eigen(A, symmetric=F)` is wrong
2. There is a numerical precision issue
3. I am incorrect in assuming this matrix should be unitary

Thanks in advance

```
#generate sample data
set.seed(0)
n <- 3
A <- matrix(runif(n^2), n)

#eigendecomposition
eigen_A <- eigen(A, symmetric=F)

#get unitary matrix U from eigenbasis
U <- eigen_A$vectors

#compute conjugate tranpose of U
U_conjugate_transpose <- Conj(t.default(U))
print(U_conjugate_transpose)

#compute inverse of U
U_inverse <- solve(U)
print(U_inverse)

#check equality
all.equal(U_conjugate_transpose, U_inverse)
```

I have read the documentation of the eigen function in R, and I think that my arguments are correct.
I expected that the inverse of U would equal its conjugate transpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's #3 (i.e., you are incorrect in assuming the eigenvector matrix should be unitary in this case). The documentation for [ALGLIB](https://www.alglib.net/eigen/nonsymmetric/nonsymmetricevd.php) (a numerical analysis library) says

> As opposed to the symmetric problem, the eigenvalues a of non-symmetric matrix do not form an orthogonal system

Going into a little more detail, [these notes from a Stanford linear algebra course](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cme335/lecture4sup.pdf) point out that the *Schur decomposition* `A = Q^H T Q` decomposes a square nonsymmetric matrix `A` into a quadratic form involving a unitary matrix `Q` and an upper-triangular matrix `T` "whose diagonal elements are the eigenvalues of `A`" ...

> However, for a general matrix A, there is no relation between Schur vectors of A and eigenvectors of A

Comment: Note that, for real matrices, there is a real Schur factorization, where `T` is only upper quasi-triangular (having 1-by-1 and 2-by-2 diagonal blocks) and the eigenvalues of `A` are the eigenvalues of the diagonal blocks, rather than of the diagonal elements.  That is computed by `Matrix::Schur` ...